# How to setup Sentry-cli source maps with react-native

Tags: react-native, sentry, react-native-sentry

## Introduction

Hi, I'm trying to get Sentry to recognise our sourcemaps in a react-native project, but I can't get it working.

The artifacts *are* uploading - I can see them in the WebUI, but the events lack context/mapping:
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

## Question

Can anyone see any problems in my setup?

Thanks!

## Background

### Assumptions

- uploading release artifacts, then deleting artifacts from web ui, then re-uploading new artifacts is valid
- `"abs_path": "app:///index.bundle",` requires the bundled js needs to be renamed to `index.bundle`
- That fact that all events have a processing error: `Discarded invalid parameter 'dist'` should not effect sourcemaps
- Once everything lines up, all my historical events for the release will benefit from the uploaded files/sourcemaps

### Xcode build phase

During the XCode build phase we already bundle the DSym.

In this script, I'm trying to pull out the bundled js and sourcemap, and uploading it.

#### Script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# WARNING: Run directly from Xcode

# For testing of Xcode bundling/sentry locally, set to "true"
DEBUG_FORCE_BUNDLING="true"

printf "Xcode: Bundle react-native and upload to Sentry"

source ../scripts/xcode/utils/node_activate.sh

# Create bundle and sourcemap
export NODE_BINARY=node
export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties
DEST=$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH
export EXTRA_PACKAGER_ARGS="--sourcemap-output $DEST/main.bundle.map.js";
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
    FORCE_BUNDLING="$DEBUG_FORCE_BUNDLING" \
    ../node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli react-native xcode \
    ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
else
   FORCE_BUNDLING="$DEBUG_FORCE_BUNDLING" \
   ../node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli react-native xcode \
   ../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
fi

# Copy bundle & sourcemap
mkdir -p ../.xcodebuild
cp $DEST/main.jsbundle ../.xcodebuild/index.bundle # rename?
cp $DEST/main.bundle.map.js ../.xcodebuild
echo "Size of file $(wc -c ../.xcodebuild/index.bundle)" # RENAME!?
echo "Size of sourcemap $(wc -c ../.xcodebuild/main.bundle.map.js)"

# Upload sentry release
# https://docs.sentry.io/cli/releases/#creating-releases
APP_IDENTIFIER="com.mycompany.app"
VERSION="1.4.21"
RELEASE_NAME="$APP_IDENTIFIER-$VERSION"
DISTRIBUTION_NAME="2400"

function sentry_release {
    npx sentry-cli releases \
        files $RELEASE_NAME \
        $1 $2 $3
        --dist $DISTRIBUTION_NAME \
        --strip-prefix ".build" \
        --ignore node_modules \
        --rewrite "$(pwd)"

}

sentry_release upload ../.xcodebuild/index.bundle '~/index.bundle'
echo "sentry_release upload"

sentry_release upload-sourcemaps ../.xcodebuild/main.bundle.map.js
echo "sentry_release upload-sourcemaps"

echo `date`
echo "DONE"
```

**Note**: The important bit of `node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh` is:

```sh
BUNDLE_FILE="$DEST/main.jsbundle"

echo "BUNDLE_FILE: $BUNDLE_FILE" > ~/bh/react-native-native/bundle.log

"$NODE_BINARY" $NODE_ARGS "$CLI_PATH" $BUNDLE_COMMAND \
  $CONFIG_ARG \
  --entry-file "$ENTRY_FILE" \
  --platform ios \
  --dev $DEV \
  --reset-cache \
  --bundle-output "$BUNDLE_FILE" \
  --assets-dest "$DEST" \
  $EXTRA_PACKAGER_ARGS
```

#### Script output

```
Xcode: Upload Debug Symbols to SentryNow using node v11.11.0 (npm v6.7.0)
FORCE_BUNDLING enabled; continuing to bundle.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-cvfhlrosjrphnjdcngyqxnlmjjbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TheApp.app/main.jsbundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheApp-cvfhlrosjrphnjdcngyqxnlmjjbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TheApp.app/main.bundle.map.js
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 109 asset files
info Done copying assets
Size of file  8477623 ../.xcodebuild/index.bundle
Size of sourcemap  15378754 ../.xcodebuild/main.bundle.map.js
A 560eaee15f0c1ccb5a57b68b5dc1b4944cff84d2  (8477623 bytes)
sentry_release upload
> Analyzing 1 sources
> Adding source map references
> Uploading source maps for release com.mycompany.app-1.4.21

Source Map Upload Report
  Source Maps
    ~/main.bundle.map.js
sentry_release upload-sourcemaps
Fri May 3 15:50:26 BST 2019
DONE
```

### Sentry event JSON

Trimmed some breadcrumbs/callstack:

```
// 20190503154011
// https://sentry.mycompany.com/mycompany/react-native-app/issues/4205/events/396945/json/

{
  "id": "1c754ed7d651445eb48ed79c995073e2",
  "project": 11,
  "release": "com.mycompany.app-1.4.21",
  "platform": "cocoa",
  "culprit": "crash(app:///index.bundle)",
  "message": "Error Sentry: TEST crash crash(app:///index.bundle)",
  "datetime": "2019-05-03T14:32:25.000000Z",
  "time_spent": null,
  "tags": [
    [
      "logger",
      "javascript"
    ],
    [
      "sentry:user",
      "id:b5f212b4-9112-4253-86cc-11583ac1945a"
    ],
    [
      "sentry:release",
      "com.mycompany.app-1.4.21"
    ],
    [
      "level",
      "fatal"
    ],
    [
      "device",
      "iPhone9,1"
    ],
    [
      "device.family",
      "iOS"
    ],
    [
      "os",
      "iOS 12.1"
    ],
    [
      "os.name",
      "iOS"
    ],
    [
      "os.rooted",
      "no"
    ]
  ],
  "contexts": {
    "device": {
      "model_id": "simulator",
      "family": "iOS",
      "simulator": true,
      "type": "device",
      "storage_size": 499963170816,
      "free_memory": 274915328,
      "memory_size": 17179869184,
      "boot_time": "2019-04-29T07:53:06Z",
      "timezone": "GMT+1",
      "model": "iPhone9,1",
      "usable_memory": 16463810560,
      "arch": "x86"
    },
    "app": {
      "app_version": "1.4.21",
      "app_name": "MyApp",
      "device_app_hash": "<device_app_hash>",
      "app_id": "<app_id>",
      "app_build": "2400",
      "app_start_time": "2019-05-03T14:31:33Z",
      "app_identifier": "com.mycompany.app",
      "type": "default",
      "build_type": "simulator"
    },
    "os": {
      "rooted": false,
      "kernel_version": "Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64",
      "version": "12.1",
      "build": "17G65",
      "type": "os",
      "name": "iOS"
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "invalid_attribute",
      "name": "dist"
    }
  ],
  "extra": {
    "session:duration": 52129
  },
  "fingerprint": [
    "{{ default }}"
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "type": "Error",
    "value": "Sentry: TEST crash"
  },
  "received": 1556893946.0,
  "sdk": {
    "client_ip": "109.69.86.251",
    "version": "0.42.0",
    "name": "sentry.javascript.react-native"
  },
  "sentry.interfaces.Breadcrumbs": {
    "values": [
      {
        "category": "console",
        "timestamp": 1556893700.0,
        "message": "%c prev state color: #9E9E9E; font-weight: bold [object Object]",
        "type": "default"
      },
      {
        "category": "console",
        "timestamp": 1556893941.0,
        "message": "%c prev state color: #9E9E9E; font-weight: bold [object Object]",
        "type": "default"
      },
      {
        "category": "console",
        "timestamp": 1556893941.0,
        "message": "%c next state color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold [object Object]",
        "type": "default"
      },
      {
        "category": "sentry",
        "timestamp": 1556893945.0,
        "message": "Error: Sentry: TEST crash",
        "type": "default",
        "level": "fatal"
      }
    ]
  },
  "sentry.interfaces.Exception": {
    "exc_omitted": null,
    "values": [
      {
        "stacktrace": {
          "frames": [
            {
              "function": "callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue",
              "platform": "javascript",
              "abs_path": "app:///[native code]",
              "in_app": false,
              "filename": "app:///[native code]"
            },
            {
              "function": "touchableHandlePress",
              "abs_path": "app:///index.bundle",
              "in_app": false,
              "platform": "javascript",
              "lineno": 64988,
              "colno": 47,
              "filename": "app:///index.bundle"
            },
            {
              "function": "crash",
              "abs_path": "app:///index.bundle",
              "in_app": false,
              "platform": "javascript",
              "lineno": 93710,
              "colno": 22,
              "filename": "app:///index.bundle"
            }
          ],
          "has_system_frames": false,
          "frames_omitted": null
        },
        "mechanism": null,
        "raw_stacktrace": null,
        "value": "Sentry: TEST crash",
        "thread_id": 99,
        "module": null,
        "type": "Error"
      }
    ]
  },
  "sentry.interfaces.User": {
    "id": "b5f212b4-9112-4253-86cc-11583ac1945a"
  },
  "type": "error",
  "version": "7"
}
```

### Artifacts

#### Web UI

Cut and pasted from Release artifacts page:

```
Release com.mycompany.app-1.4.21

Artifacts
NAME                    SIZE
~/index.bundle          8.1 MB
~/main.bundle.map.js    14.7 MB
```

#### sourceMappingURL

```sh
$ tail -c 50 .xcodebuild/main.jsbundle
//# sourceMappingURL=main.bundle.map.js
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After MONTHS, we realised we had to write client code to knit in the Distribution and Release....

```js
    const configureSentry = () => {
        Sentry.config(config.sentry.dsn).install();
        Sentry.setDist(DeviceInfo.getBuildNumber());
        Sentry.setRelease(DeviceInfo.getBundleId() + '-' + DeviceInfo.getVersion());
    };
```